# Issue Signing InstallShield 2012 LE Installer Via Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installshield, code-signing, installshield-2012

I'm trying to sign my setup package from within InstallShield 2012LE in Visual Studio 2012.  I have an MS Authenticode Cert from Symantec (VeriSign).  There are two issues I'm seeing.

Firstly if I select Sign Output Files -> Setup.exe and Windows Installer Package (Or just windows installer package) visual studio crashes.  Event Log shows two errors

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011ecaa
```

Faulting module name: WINTRUST.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16420, time stamp: 0x505a9691
Exception code: 0xc0000005

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 758017E4
Stack:
```

Also if I set "Use Software Identification Tag" to yes then I get the following error when trying to build the installer package.

```
Error   108 -1027: Failed signing TagCreatorID_EE17CD21-FE17-4342-8CA5-E0B993AAEB3E.swidtag
ISEXP : error : -1027: Failed signing TagCreatorID_EE17CD21-FE17-4342-8CA5-E0B993AAEB3E.swidtag
```

Has anyone come across these issues before and know of a workaround?  It works fine is I turn off Software Identification Tag and only sign Setup.exe but I also require the options above.  The certificate also signs all my DLLs and EXEs without issue.